# ImageView add to the map and drag Api V2

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to add an image on the GoogleMap and I can drag it there.
Make no mistake, it is not a label I want. It is an ImageView.

Comment: What do you mean by add image to Google Maps? If you want Ground overlays with image overlays that are tied to latitude/longitude coordinates https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/groundoverlay or you can use this too https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3433053?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkTouch/) showing drag-and-drop movement of markers on a Google Map in Android.

It uses onTouchEvent() to detect when the user touches and holds their finger near a marker. It then removes the marker from the overlay, but puts the same image over top of the map using RelativeLayout. Then, on "move" touch events, the image is moved (faster than forcing the whole overlay to redraw). When the finger is lifted, the image is removed, but the marker is put back in the overlay at the new spot.